# cs50 pset4/less reflect check50 not working

Tags: c, cs50

My code compiles and runs properly but when I use check50 it says none of the 'requirements' are met.

```
:( reflect correctly filters 1x2 image
    expected "0 0 255\n255 0...", not "3 0 0\n0 0 255..."
:( reflect correctly filters 1x3 image
    expected "0 0 255\n0 255...", not "246 55 65\n0 2..."
:( reflect correctly filters image that is its own mirror image
    expected "255 0 0\n255 0...", not "0 255 0\n255 0..."
:( reflect correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 80 90\n40 5...", not "110 130 140\n4..."
:( reflect correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "100 110 120\n7...", not "110 130 140\n1..."
```

Code:

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    void swap (RGBTRIPLE*, RGBTRIPLE*);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        int n = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < width / 2; j++)
        {
            swap (&image[i][j], &image[i][(width - j)]);
            n++;
        }
    }
     return;
}
void swap (RGBTRIPLE*a, RGBTRIPLE*b)
 {
    RGBTRIPLE tempArray;
    RGBTRIPLE tempArray2;
    tempArray = *a;
    tempArray2 = *b;
    *a = tempArray2;
    *b = tempArray;
}
```

I've looked through many other posts and I cant find any solution. It might just be some small detail bu I can't find it. 
any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `j == 0` and you execute

```
swap (&image[i][j], &image[i][(width - j)]);
```

What are the indices of the elements swapped? Are they legal?

Answer (score 1):

It might be something as simple as your swap function call.  The second argument of swap might work better if it was

```
swap (&image[i][j], &image[i][width-1-j])
```

That won't make much of a difference to the eye, but it might make a big difference to the Cs50 check program.